# Move mailbox to public folder

Tags: exchange-2007

I need some help moving a users mailbox to a public folder.

I'm not really a sysadmin, I know some AD and Windows Server, but Exchange is new stuff to me.

Basically, one user has left the company, so we disabled his account in the AD, but now it's time for the mail. I need to move his old mail to a mailbox which the owern of the company and I can acess, then I would like to forward any new emails to that public folde

How can I do this with Exchange 2007?

Comment: As its Exchange 2007, Public Folders are deprecated so depending on your exchange configuration may not even be present on the server. I'd suggest just leaving the account "as is" and logging in via outlook web access, personally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics for Exchange, but if you have IMAP maybe it's easier to use [`imapfilter`](http://imapfilter.hellug.gr/).

`imapfilter` actions are configured with a simple **[lua](http://www.lua.org/) script** (I don't know lua myself and it was quite easy to create actions).

This is an example of a `~/.imapfilter/config.lua`:

```
---------------
--  Options  --
---------------

options.timeout = 120
options.subscribe = true


----------------
--  Accounts  --
----------------

user_that_leaves = IMAP {
    server = 'yourserver',
    username = 'userthatleaves',
    password = 'swordfish',
    ssl = 'ssl3',
}

public_account = IMAP {
    server = 'yourserver',
    username = 'public_account',
    password = 'dicklaurentisdead',
    ssl = 'ssl3',
}

user_that_leaves.INBOX:move_messages(public_account.INBOX)
```

Answer (score 0):

not answering the question directly, but why not export the mailbox to a PST file (using Exchange Management Shell) then disable the exchange account?

```
Export-Mailbox -Identity <MailboxIdParameter> -PSTFolderPath <Path_Of_PST_Folder>\<File_Name>.pst
```

If you hit problems exporting ensure you have the correct permissions:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity <MailboxIdParameter> -User myAdminUser -AccessRights FullAccess
```

You can add an additional email address to the Owner's account once the exchange account is disabled to catch any new mail.